# Angular JS Cancel Window Event

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, event-handling

I'm currently checking for window refresh and back with angular by using:

```
   @HostListener('window:beforeunload') //Refresh
   beforeUnload() { this.showDialog = true; }

   @HostListener('window:popstate') //Back
   popState() { this.showDialog = true; }
```

Inside these events I plan on adding a popup (which I have the functionality for already with a boolean and *ngIf component). I want to only refresh/back if the dialog is success. How would I cancel the refresh/back event? Is it even possible. 

Thanks

I know I'm supposed to show a solution but I've browsed google and have no clue how to tackle this. I assumed this would work but it didn't:

```
    beforeUnload() { return; }
```

Comment: You cloud use | @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) | to access the event object on the handler and then use | $event.preventDefault() | $event.stopPropagation() | this should work

Comment: How would I pass the event object to the function. What I have isn't working.  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  popState($event: any) {
    console.log('Back');
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
  }

Comment: Try something like this:  `@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) onBeforeUnload(event: any) { event.preventDefault(); ...  }`

Comment: Ok, so the beforeunload event worked. It's only the popevent. When I console.log the event object it says cancelable:false. Since I'm using a router beforeunload isn't called sometimes on back button press. How could I do the same with back button

Comment: Are you using the angular Router?